# printf() redirection to file in command line (Cygwin)

Tags: c, cygwin

I've got a C program that's supposed to work on command line interface taking few arguments - to do that I'm using Cygwin.

I want to know if it's possible to printf some prompts into command like - things like "Give a number:" before I get data (program needs to prompt for a couple of things) and get the final result redirected to file. Or if I'm redirecting to file I need to just resign myself to the fact that I can't print anything and everything goes into the file?

Essentialy I'd like something like this:

```
printf("Please enter any number:");//prompting for some variable
scanf("%d", &some_variable);
function_printing_its_output();//a nodescript function that at the end uses printf() to get results on screen
```

Now I was wondering if it's possible to make the first printf() prompt appear in command lie (possibly using different function if it exists) but have the function output go into the file (and I cannot directly make it print to file, the program needs to use `./program_name some_stuff file1 > file2` format to work redirecting to file2).

Comment: You could have your prompt go to `stderr` using `fprintf(stderr, "...");`.

Comment: If you are in Windows Visual C you can use `cprintf` to send prompts to the console and `printf` to send program output to `stdout`.

Comment: @lurker Thanks that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could have your prompt go to `stderr` using `fprintf(stderr, "...");`.
                    – lurker